# Could not find a base address that matches scheme http for the endpoint with binding WSHttpBinding. Registered base address schemes are [https]

Tags: c#, wcf, web-config, wshttpbinding

I've been to several sites on how to correct this error and can't get rid of the error. I'm hosting it on IIS 6 with SSL enabled. Below is my configuration

```
 <services>
            <service behaviorConfiguration="UsernamePasswordBehavior" name="DataServices.BEService">    

                <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpsBinding" name="mex" contract="IMetadataExchange"  listenUri="https://mysite/beservice.svc"/>

                <endpoint address="wsbe" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="wsHttpWithUsernamePassword"
                    name="BEwsHttp" contract="DataServices.IBEService" listenUri="https://mysite/beservice.svc" />               
            </service>
</services>

    <bindings>          
        <wsHttpBinding>
                    <binding name="wsHttpWithUsernamePassword" sendTimeout="00:06:00"  receiveTimeout="00:06:00">
                        <security mode="Message">
                            <message clientCredentialType="UserName"/>
                            </security>                    
                    </binding>
            </wsHttpBinding>
        </bindings>


     <behaviors>
                <serviceBehaviors>
                   <behavior name="UsernamePasswordBehavior">
                        <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
                        <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />                    
                        <serviceCredentials>
                            <userNameAuthentication userNamePasswordValidationMode="Custom" customUserNamePasswordValidatorType="DataServices.CustomUsernameValidator, DataServices" />
                            <serviceCertificate findValue="*.mysite.com" storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="My"  x509FindType="FindBySubjectName"/>                        
                        </serviceCredentials>                                      
                    </behavior>                
                </serviceBehaviors>
            </behaviors>
```

Hope someone can help!

Comment: Did you try to remove the http point in IIS and only have the SSL?

Comment: Is The `SSL Required` flag turned on in the SSL settings?

Comment: Yes, 'Require SSL' is set in IIS. Can't remove the TCP port.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the IIS web site instance you're hosting under is only configured for HTTPS (SSL). Right click the web site instance and choose "Edit Bindings...". Do you see port 80 (plain HTTP) listed there? Also check the "SSL Settings" feature to make sure the "Always require" option is not turned on. - Taken from Stack overflow itself. It can work as you are using only message security in your config,there has to be an non-HTTPS/SSL address bound to the site. 
Has your code worked when you use self signed certificate on local machine?

Comment: Yes, it does work with a self signed cert on a dev box. This is IIS6 so the menu is a bit different. In Directory Security>Secure Communications, Require Secure Channel (SSL) is checked.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use

```
<security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
```

For your security mode, rather than Message ?